# How can I redirect a page based on the client's browser with JavaScript (or other)?

Tags: javascript, redirect, web

**Today, I was making my website, when I realized some of my scripts and styles could not be used on older versions of browsers.** So, I was wondering if it was possible to check exactly what browser and browser version using JavaScript, and have it automatically redirect to a different page? (e.g: http://lypi.ml/en-us/browserType?=firefox_1.0.0) *Thank you! :)* And **PLEASE** list all browser scripts!

Comment: have you tried to google it? there are loads of examples over the internet

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is [browser detection using the user agent.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) If you look at `navigator.userAgent` you'll be able to glean a lot of information about the current browser. Here's what your browser reports:

```js
console.log(navigator.userAgent);
```

However, user agent is sniffing is almost never the answer. To quote the page I linked to previously:

> Note: It's worth re-iterating: it's very rarely a good idea to use user agent sniffing. You can almost always find a better, more broadly compatible way to solve your problem!

The user agent string is unreliable and full of lies. For example, if I run the code above on Chrome 51, it has Mozilla in the string. The format switches around all of the time and there's nothing that requires browsers to report accurate information. Really, you're just relying on good faith to get any good information out of the user agent string.

You should absolutely consider more robust ways of handling different browsers. For example, only write your code in a cross-browser format or use a number of tools which will compile your code into a compatible format.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

this code help you,

If browser be IE7,  automatically redirect to google site .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="x"></p>
        <script>
            var x = document.getElementById("x");
            var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
            if(userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 7.0")!=-1)
                window.location = "https://www.google.com";
            else
                x.innerHTML = "Other browsers";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways to redirect that I myself know of, but I'm not sure if they'll exactly work for you.

```
<script language="javascript">
    location.replace("http://www.yournewsite.com");
</script>
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://www.yournewsite.com">
```

I do hope this or anyone's answer helps! Have a wonderful day.

Information related to my answer can be found [here](http://www.angelfire.com/nm/thehtmlsource/jazzup/redirect.html).

Comment: You're right that this will cause a redirect but OP wants to redirect based on what browser the user is using.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The question was about determining the users' browser, and then redirecting accordingly.